# jQuery CSS selector is returning a value wrapped in two sets of double quotes

Tags: jquery, css

I am doing a very simply jQuery select, using a CSS property. Oddly, the value is being returned wrapped in two sets of double quotes?

```
var font = $(this).css('font-family');
```

Result comes back as:

```
font:""Jockey One""
```

Comment: Please post the code that renders the value (`console.log()` or `alert()` or whatever you're using).

Comment: are you using the font name like `"Jockey One"` in your css?

Comment: can you show how you get that value?

Comment: take a look at this fiddle, it works just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/v3qtx96f/

Comment: Fredeirc - doing so now. Amin - I am using: style="font-family:'Jockey One'" (I also tried without single quotes, same issue) Guradio - I am using the jQuery selector, and checking using Chrome Inspector and breakpoints

Comment: try changing the value in the fiddle I made to see what is 'causing the issue

Comment: There should be no problem with this. The problem might be where you are displaying the font value.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my Inspector. Note the `font` var value and then look at the output in the console (which is spat out via console.log() on the line underneath) http://imgur.com/RhiKCCz

Comment: I tried this <input type="text" id="abcd" style="
    font-family: fantasy;
"> var font = $('#abcd').css('font-family'); returning "fantasy"

Answer (score 1):

font names containing a space are quoted and your font variable is a string. hence the double set of quotes. if you want to ignore the quotes in quoted font names, just do this:

```
var font = $(this).css('font-family');
font = font.replace(/["']/g, "");
console.log(font);
```

Comment: Question is about cause of issue not solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

> Font family names containing whitespace should be quoted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#Values

Also javascript return `font-family` name in quote.

```js
console.log($(".noSpace").css("font-family"));
console.log($(".withSpace").css("font-family"));
```

```css
.noSpace {
    font-family: "JockeyOne";
}

.withSpace {
    font-family: "Jockey One";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="noSpace"></div>
<div class="withSpace"></div>
```